# Is it safe to kill thread using only stack variables?

Tags: multithreading, kill

I have a fortran subroutine. It runs quite long time once started.

Now, I want to write a program which calls the fortran subroutine from C++ in a thread.
The thread should be stopped(or canceled) when user requested.
But the subroutine does not support any method to terminate the calculation during it running.

As far as I know, the subroutine uses only stack variables(no allocation).
The subroutine is given by static library for windows(.lib file).

In this case, may I assume that killing the subroutine thread does not causes any problem such as resource leaking?

FYI, here's the running environment:

- OS: Windows 7 64bit or above
- Compiler: MSVC 2015 for C++, Intel Parallel Studio for fortran

Comment: You won't have any stack/heap leaks direct to your code in your case, but if you kill a thread (i.e. force kill it versus just letting end normally), then the OS could have a leak since it might not have cleaned up the underlying thread handles properly .. Is the Fortran call something that is invoked through runtime API's, or is it a process? You could do some sort of control loop in the thread that checks a `do_run` flag, and when `do_run` is false (through user intervention), the loop ends and Fortran process could be killed that way (or some other hook to stop it) ...?

Comment: @txtechhelp Thank you for your comment. I really want to add some flag to exit thread gracefully, too. However, I do not have the source code of the subroutine. I have only it as a library, so modifying the subroutine is not an option for me, sadly.

Comment: @txtechhelp And, I have a prototype of the subroutine to call it from C/C++ and the subroutine is called directly from C++ side. As far as I know the subroutine just runs some matrix calculations.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this question with certainty, especially since we don't know what OS, compiler, etc. we're talking about. I would suggest some rigorous testing.

Comment: If it's a library call, that is, if you're prototype goes into another DLL/SO file, then you might be out of luck; about the most you might be able to achieve is spawning the thread and then using a sync object to detect when it's done.

Comment: @CareyGregory I added some environment information. Thank you.

Comment: @txtechhelp What about static library? It's inside of a .lib file.

Comment: Correct. Unless there is an API that can be called to set another flag to stop the matrix processing, your code is at bay of the external call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's not safe -- there are other resources that the thread could acquire besides memory.  For example, it could lock a mutex, and if you killed the thread while the mutex was locked, the mutex would remain locked forever, with the likely result that other threads would deadlock waiting forever to acquire the mutex.  If you really have no way to get the thread to exit cleanly/voluntarily, then the only safe approach is to spawn a child process and run the routine inside the child process.  You can safely kill the child process if you have to, because the OS will automatically clean up any resources that were allocated by the child process.